# Wrong number converting int to string c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I have simple coin counter, in 2d Unity game. But It's count one coin as 2. I think that it's because of wrong converting int to string.

```
public GameObject coin; // Gameobject with coin
public Text CoinCounter; // Text with counter that shows in game
private float TotalCounter = 0; // Float for counting total amount of picked up coins

{
   TotalCounter = Convert.ToInt32((CoinCounter.text)); // Converting text counter to Numbers
}

private void Update()
{

    TotalCounter = Convert.ToInt32((CoinCounter.text)); // Updating Counter evry frame update 
    Debug.Log(TotalCounter); // Showing Counter  in Console 
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    TotalCounter = (TotalCounter + 1); // adding 1 to total amount when player touching coin 
    CoinCounter.text = TotalCounter.ToString(); // Converting to Text, and showing up in UI





    coin.SetActive(false); // Hiding coin


}
```

So, in Debug Log it's showing right Total amount, but in UI, It's Showing wrong number. As example, When Total Amount is 1 it's showing 2 etc.

Comment: I dont understand this part: `{
   TotalCounter = Convert.ToInt32((CoinCounter.text)); // Converting text counter to Numbers
}` can you please explain what that is? a method? a setter?

Comment: Why is TotalCounter declared as a float and not an integer? It also looks like you have a missing method declaration in the code above.

Comment: is there any value update event occurs in UI level? like when the data will come from the this blocks, do you update them again with +1

Comment: Why do you need to read TotalCounter from text box in update, i dont think that is necessary here, just update text and total counter whenever you hit a coin

Comment: @Andrew


> Why is TotalCounter declared as a float and not an integer?  

Float and int can hold same types of value (int can't hold decimal numbers, I know, but float can hold regular numbers), didn't they?  

> It also looks like you have a missing method declaration in the code above.  

Whant method it's not declarated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not in converting, trigger worked twice. Need check if the coin is enabled before disabling it and adding to the coin counter. Eg:

```
 if (coin.activeSelf)
  {
      coin.SetActive(false);

      Debug.Log("Object is not active ");

      TotalCounter += 1;
      Debug.Log("Total Counter + :" + TotalCounter);
      CoinCounter.text = TotalCounter.ToString();
      Debug.Log("Text after +:" + CoinCounter.text);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it in `Update` but only when you actually change it.

The method you are looking for is probably [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.6)

you should use `int` for amounts (unless will you have values like `1.5` coins later)

Than you execute your code everytime it collides ... with anything. You should only collide with a coin instead. Either use tags or compare with the referenced value in your case

```
public GameObject Coin; // Gameobject with coin
public Text CoinCounter; // Text with counter that shows in game
private int _totalCounter = 0; // Int for counting total amount of picked up coins

// I guess it's supposed to be Start here
void Start()
{
   // Converting text counter to Numbers
   int.TryParse(CoinCounter.text, out _totalCounter); 
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject != Coin) return;

    // later this should probably rather be
    //if(collision.gameObject.tag != "Coin") return

    _totalCounter += 1; // adding 1 to total amount when player touching coin 
    CoinCounter.text = _totalCounter.ToString(); // Converting to Text, and showing up in UI

    Coin.SetActive(false); // Hiding coin

    // later this should probably rather be
    //collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write your convertor code into the trigger void , after that check it ; this might be happened because of update function, try like that and check again:    `

```
public GameObject coin;
public Text CoinCounter;
private float TotalCounter = 0; 
private void Update()
{}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    TotalCounter = (TotalCounter + 1); 
    Debug.Log(TotalCounter); 
    CoinCounter.text = TotalCounter.ToString(); 
    Debug.Log(CoinCounter.text);
    coin.SetActive(false); 
}
```

`